# NSManagedObjectContext in inconsistent state after mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification in background context

Tags: ios, core-data, merge, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm experiencing some strange behaviour in CoreData that causes one of my MOCs to end up in an inconsistent state. I've replicated the issue in a small sample [project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t4300vxkixh9j6r/tester.zip)

Here is a basic rundown of my situation:

- I have two entity types, pipelines and boxes. Each pipeline can contain 0 or more boxes, and each box is part of exactly one pipeline
- In my sample project:

  - I'm creating 1 pipeline and 3 sample boxes all pointing to that pipeline.
  - This sample data is created on a MOC that was created with `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`
  - I create a background MOC (`NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType') and fetch all the boxes and delete just one of them.
  - this delete causes the pipeline to be updated (there should be one less box in the relationship)
  - When I save the background MOC, I try to merge the changes into the main queue MOC

The problem is that after the merge, the main queue context successfully merged the delete but did not merge the edit to the pipeline which should show that there is one less box in the relation.

Somehow its not merging the entire change.

Here's some of the code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    // create a core database and a moc on the ui thread
    [self initCoreData];

    // fill up db with dummy data all on the main thread
    [self createDummyData:self.uiContext];

    [self printUIContextContents];

    // now create a background moc
    NSManagedObjectContext* backgroundContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];

    // when the backgrouynd context saves, merge changees in to UI context
    [backgroundContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        backgroundContext.mergePolicy = [[NSMergePolicy alloc] initWithMergeType:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicyType];
        [backgroundContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:self.persistentCoordinator];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(mocDidSave:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:backgroundContext];
    }];


    // now delete a box on background thread
    [backgroundContext performBlock:^{
        NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Box"];
        request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@", @"box1"];

        NSError* error = nil;
        NSArray* boxes = [backgroundContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
        if (error != nil){
            NSLog(@"Error in deleting box: %@", error);
        }

        Box* box = (Box*)boxes[0];

        [backgroundContext deleteObject:box];
        [backgroundContext save:nil];
    }];

    [self printUIContextContents];


    return YES;
}

- (void) printUIContextContents {
    [self.uiContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Pipeline"];
        NSArray* pipelines = [self.uiContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
        for (Pipeline* pipeline in pipelines) {
            NSLog(@"Pipeline Name: %@", pipeline.name);
            NSLog(@"\tBoxes that are in the pipeline relationship: ");
            for (Box* box in pipeline.boxes) {
                NSLog(@"\t\t%@", box.name);
            }
        }

        NSLog(@" ");

        request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Box"];
        NSArray* boxes = [self.uiContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
        NSLog(@"All Boxes Entities Present:");
        for (Box* box in boxes) {
            NSLog(@"\t%@", box.name);
        }
        NSLog(@" ");
        NSLog(@" ");
    }];
}

- (void)mocDidSave:(NSNotification *)notif {

    [self.uiContext performBlockAndWait:^(void) {
        [self.uiContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notif];
    }];
}


- (void) createDummyData:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context {
    NSArray* boxNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"box1", @"box2", @"box3", nil];
    NSString* pipelineName = @"pipeline1";

    [self.uiContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        Pipeline* pipe = (Pipeline*)[self createEntity:@"Pipeline" inContext:self.uiContext];
        pipe.name = pipelineName;

        for (NSString* boxName in boxNames) {
            Box* box = (Box*)[self createEntity:@"Box" inContext:self.uiContext];
            box.name = boxName;
            box.pipeline = pipe;
        }

        NSError* error = nil;
        [self.uiContext save:&error];
        if (error != nil){
            NSLog(@"Error in create dummy data: %@", error);
        }
    }];
}


- (void) initCoreData {
    NSURL* modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Model" withExtension:@"momd"];
    NSURL* storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"StreakDB.sqlite"];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil];

    NSManagedObjectModel* objectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

    NSError *error = nil;
    self.persistentCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:objectModel];
    if (![self.persistentCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        /*
         SOME ERROR HANDLING HERE
         */
    }

    self.uiContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    [self.uiContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:self.persistentCoordinator];
    self.uiContext.mergePolicy = [[NSMergePolicy alloc] initWithMergeType:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicyType];
}

- (NSManagedObject*)createEntity:(NSString *)entityType inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {
    return [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:entityType
                                         inManagedObjectContext:context];
}
```

Any ideas what could be going on? Again here's a sample project that illustrates the issue (and prints out the results): [project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t4300vxkixh9j6r/tester.zip)

**UPDATE:**

Pipeline Name: pipeline1
    Boxes that are in the pipeline relationship: 
        box3
        box1
        box2

All Boxes Entities Present:
    box3
    box2
    box1

Pipeline Name: pipeline1
    Boxes that are in the pipeline relationship: 
        box3
        box1
        box2

All Boxes Entities Present:
    box3
    box2

As you can see, when I print out the uiContext the second time, its in an inconsistent state. Specifically, there are 2 boxes in the context but the pipeline has a relationship that points to 3 boxes - hence the inconsistency.

I understand that the background save may have completed before or after the second print out, but in either case, the state of the context should be consistent no? (i.e. 3 boxes, and 3 items in the relationship OR 2 boxes and 2 items in the relationship).

Comment: Try making the background context a chile context of the UI context instead of observing and merging. Also ensure you cascade and nil rules are set correctly on you relationships in the model.

Comment: It does work if I use parent and child contexts but I'd like to know why the merging doesn't work. I feel like I'm missing some fundamental core data concept.

Comment: Delete rules are all setup correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This might be as threading issue (you are executing the BG operation in parallel). try changing it to: `[backgroundContext performBlockAndWait: ...];`

**Elaboration:**
The context is not in an inconsistent state.
Why?

**0: Each fetch request is a trip to the store, and is not relying on the data the context contain in the moment of execution, the retrieved objects are matched against the existing row cache of the context in order to reuse the existing items information and prevent duplication of items in the context, you get a snapshot of the current store status.**

What actually going on is:
1. You create items in MOC1 (main context), and then log objects using a 2 phase fetch request.
1.1. since (0), each fetch request may return a different data set if the underlying store was change in between fetches
2. You create MOC2 that uses another thread to perform its operations, but its creation is blocking MOC1's thread (the main thread).
2.1. You execute an asynchronous block using MOC2 thread.
2.2. MOC2 is deleting some objects
2.3. MOC2 save its changes (the store was changed here, before the merge)
2.4. MOC2 is trying to merge the changes to MOC1 but can't as MOC1's thread is busy executing your log function (see (3.)).
**3. Note** that the main thread is now entering your log function again and the current run loop had not exited yet (in paralel to 2.1. operation), so merging to MOC1 will not be possible untile the main runloop finish its cycle.
3.1. MOC1 execute log function 1st fetch request (in all probability, before MOC2 have a change to save its changes to the store, this request will block the coordinator so that even if MOC2 is ready to save the coordinator will be blocked until the first fetch is completed.
3.1.1. You get box1,box2,box3
3.2. MOC1 execute the 2nd fetch request (in all probability, after MOC2 saved to the store)
3.2.1. You get box2,box3
4. The main runloop end and MOC2 can now merge its changes to MOC1

Hope this clarifies a bit.

Try logging after you merge changes to MOC1 and see that things are as they should be.

When dealing with multiple threads, you need to synchronise your MOCs by either using notifications (as you did), or use parent child architecture.

In a parent child architecture, this will not happen, but the context doing the actual write to the store will be the main context, and this will block your main thread.

Comment: That ofcourse works. This is a dummy app so it doesn't make a difference here. But in my real app I don't want to performBlockAndWait otherwise my main thread  would block until the operation was completed. I want to perform the save in the background and then merge the changes into the uiContext when its done.

Comment: That is exactly the results you should expect. The first fetch in the second verification is done before the BG context save, and the second fetch is done after the save. if you were to use a FRC you would get consistent results as it would be updated only after the merge to the main context.